# std::construct_at to use memory from std::byte / unsigned char arrays

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++20, lifetime, object-model

It is a very common example to use `std::byte` / `unsigned char` arrays with `std::construct_at`  to provide the storage.

```
//say A is a NON standard-layout class user-defined class
alignas(A) std::byte storage[sizeof(A)];
std::construct_at(reintrepret_cast<A*>(storage), A{});
```

However, `std::construct_at` accepts a pointer to the object, while if you `reintrepre_cast` a pointer to `std::byte` / `unsigned char` array it should still point to the first member of `std::byte` / `unsigned char` array. So is the code above illegal? And if so, how to provide a valid pointer to `std::construct_at`?

Answer (score 1):

> However, std::construct_at accepts a pointer to the object, while if you reintrepre_cast a pointer to std::byte / unsigned char array it should still point to the first member of std::byte / unsigned char array.

And?

`construct_at` does not treat the pointer as if it pointed to an object within its lifetime. It does not attempt any operation on this pointer which would result in [a violation of [basic.lval]/11.](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/basic.lval#11) That is, it doesn't attempt to access a glvalue of type `T` using that pointer. Indeed, all [the C++20 standard says about its behavior](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/specialized.construct) with regard to the pointer is this:

> Equivalent to:
>
> ```
>  return ::new (voidify(*location)) T(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
> ```

Where `voidify` is [just a complicated cast to `void*`](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/specialized.algorithms#4).

Comment: _It does not attempt any operation on this pointer which would result in a violation of [basic.lval]/11_ The OP writes: _`A` is a NON standard-layout class_. [basic.lval]/11 is irrelevant for classes. https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/basic.lval#11.note-1 http://eel.is/c++draft/defns.access#sentence-2

Answer (score 0):

cppreference is not a standard so I don't see it as a reliable source. It has to be proven by a quote from the standard.

That *storage* points to the array of *unsigned char* in your example and not to *A*. Although I think the reason *construct_at* takes a pointer, is because it wants to know the type of the object it wants to construct, and the pointer to A is converted to *void* anyway by the implementation of *construct_at*. This way it is still compliant with the standard.

Note here it is said that *storage* is an array object!

> If a complete object is created ([expr.new]) in storage associated
> with another object e of type “array of N unsigned char” or of type
> “array of N std​::​byte” ([cstddef.syn]), that array provides storage
> for the created object if: (3.1) the lifetime of e has begun and not
> ended, and (3.2) the storage for the new object fits entirely within
> e, and (3.3) there is no array object that satisfies these constraints
> nested within e.

Here it says what can be done with reintepret_cast and obviously unsigned char array and A are not pointer-interconvertible.

> If two objects are pointer-interconvertible, then they have the same
> address, and it is possible to obtain a pointer to one from a pointer
> to the other via a reinterpret_cast ([expr.reinterpret.cast]). [Note
> 4: An array object and its first element are not
> pointer-interconvertible, even though they have the same address. —
> end note]

However, reintepret_cast still can be called as long as it is result is not *used* apart from converting it to another type

> An object pointer can be explicitly converted to an object pointer of
> a different type.57 When a prvalue v of object pointer type is
> converted to the object pointer type “pointer to cv T”, the result is
> static_cast<cv T*>(static_cast<cv void*>(v)).

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be worried that converting between pointers for use in `std::construct_at` is somehow problematic because you don't have an `A` object, and perhaps strict aliasing is violated in some way.

Those worries are unnecessary. The code:

> ```cpp
> std::construct_at(reinterpret_cast<A*>(storage), A{});
> ```

... is equivalent to ([[expr.reinterpret.cast] p7](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.reinterpret.cast#7)):

```cpp
std::construct_at(static_cast<A*>(static_cast<void*>(storage)), A{});
```

... which is equivalent to ([[specialized.construct] p2](http://eel.is/c++draft/specialized.construct#2)):

```cpp
// note: not an exact equivalence, because the std::construct_at version created
//       an additional temporary A{} object
::new (static_cast<void*>(static_cast<A*>(static_cast<void*>(storage)))) A{};
```

... which is equivalent to ([[expr.static.cast] p14](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.static.cast#14)):

```cpp
// note: both the conversion to and from void* leave the pointer value unchanged,
//       so they can be simplified away
// note: an array and its first element have the same address,
//       so we can use both storage and &storage
::new (static_cast<void*>(storage)) A{};
```

A conversion to `void*` doesn't require an actual object to exist. There also can't be a strict aliasing violation because you are beginning the lifetime of a new object, not accessing an existing one. Your code is valid.

Other answers in this Q&A mention pointer-interconvertibility, which is not relevant. What matters is the conversion to/from `void*`, which is a conversion that leaves the *pointer value* (and thus the address that the pointer represents) unchanged ([[conv.ptr] p2](http://eel.is/c++draft/conv.ptr#2)). Pointer-interconvertibility would only be relevant to aliasing, and none of this code is performing aliasing.